# Execute complex logic at the end of the transaction

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I have a JEE application with rich (JPA) entities (using EclipseLink, if that makes a difference). My entity has multiple methods which modify its fields. Some of these changes require a complex and time-consuming validation process, which might update and delete several related entities and can require multiple remote service calls.
Now a user of my entity might call multiple modifying methods consecutively, so I want to optimize the process so that this validation process is only called once, at the end of the transaction, instead of calling it immediately for each and every relevant method call. Also, I want this to be invisible to the callers, so that they don't have to be aware of this functionality and manually need to call a validation once they are done.

So what I would like to do is to collect the information about what parts of the entity have changed in transient fields in the entity class, and somehow trigger the validation process automatically at the latest possible time. I played around with the @PreUpdate and @PrePersist methods, but they are called during each flush, not only at the end of the transaction. I tried PreDestroy, but that obviously is too late for the service calls to still work. I also tried to use a CDI event with during=BEFORE_COMPLETION, but that caused InjectionFailedExceptions when the validation logic tried to materialize some related entities, so apparently my injection context is not available at that state.

Are there any other tools or techniques which can achieve this goal? Or maybe one of the above options should work and I am doing something wrong?

Comment: This seems like an expensive idea. Wouldn't you want to do all the calculations and validations before going to the database, rather then having the DB resources tied up for the processing?  That aside, EclipseLink has ways to access the change sets on an EntityManager or entity level (described here https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_access_what_changed_in_an_object_or_transaction.3F ).

Comment: Expensive in what way? The aim is to specifically to reduce the effort by making sure that the validation logic is only called one time, when it's sure that all updates to the entity have been done. Of course it should be done before the database update takes place, but it should also be done only when it's sure that there will be no further updates to the entity (so ideally after the last statement of the application logic and before the data is persisted). Tracking the changes is not really a problem, because the entity will log the relevant changes itself.